# List All Files that Match a Particular RegExp Along with the Number of Matches

Tags: grep, regular-expression

I want to search a directory (and any subdirectories) for files whose content match a particular regular expression and, for each file that matched, I'd like to list the number of times that the regular expression matched in that file.

For example, if the file is

```
line1
line2
line3
linea
lineb
```

And the regexp is `line\d`, then I would like to see that file with the number 3, since the first, second, and third line matched the regular expression.

How would I go about doing something like this?

Answer (score 0):

To find files recursively matching a pattern there's `find PATH -name PATTERN` - see `man find`. To search through the *contents* of those files you'd combine `find` with `grep` in `find … -exec grep PATTERN +`. Finally, GNU `grep` has a `--count`/`-c` flag to count the number of matches.

```
$ cd "$(mktemp --directory)"
$ printf '%s\n' foo bar foo > first
$ printf '%s\n' bar foo bar > second
$ printf '%s\n' bar > third
$ find . -name '*r*' -exec grep --count foo {} +
./third:0
./first:2
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can be satisfied with being restricted to `egrep` style regular expressions, and with the count only counting the number of lines that match the regular expression (rather than the number of times the regular expression matches in total), then something like this would work for you:

`$ find /directory/name -type f -print | xargs egrep -c "line[0-9]" /dev/null`

(the `/dev/null` at the end is sort of a hack, in case `xargs` breaks up the output of `find` such that the last `egrep` command it runs is invoked with exactly one filename - in which case, it would print the count, but not the filename to which that count applies).

If you want to live dangerously and try to use Perl-style regular expressions instead, you could use `grep -P` instead of `egrep`, but that may or may not work, depending on the system you're running it on.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the recursive version of `grep`.  If you just want the names of files, you can do:

```
grep -rl regex *
```

You can send the output of the above throug `wc -l` to get the number of matching files.

If you just want the number of instances in each file, you can try

```
grep -rc regex * | grep -v ":0$"
```